# Detect user skipping to end of AVPlayer video

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, avplayer, xamarin.forms

I've written a Xamarin.Forms iOS app `Page` that users an `AVPlayer` to play a video via a custom page renderer.

When the video finishes, or when the user scrubs to the end of the video (using controls created by `AVPlayerViewController`), they should be sent to the next `ContentPage` in the app.

I can track when the video 'naturally' finishes by observing the `AVPlayerItem.DidPlayToEndTimeNotification` on the `AVPlayerItem _playerItem`, like so:

```
    videoEndNotificationToken = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(
        AVPlayerItem.DidPlayToEndTimeNotification,
        VideoDidFinishPlaying,
        _playerItem);
```

I then push a new page on the navigation stack in `VideoDidFinishPlaying`, and the user continues.

However, this doesn't work if the user scrubs to the end of the video using the default control bar.

How can I detect if the video finished via being scrubbed to the end by the user?

Comment: `AVPlayer` does not have any controls, which ones are you using?

Comment: Those provided by `AVPlayerViewController`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `AVPlayerViewController` and allowing the user to manually seek to the end will not fire `DidPlayToEndTimeNotification` as the media asset did not actually play to the end 'normally'.

Here is what I did in a similar case:

#### Add a `TimeJumpedNotification`:

```
didPlayToEndTimeNotification = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(
    AVPlayerItem.DidPlayToEndTimeNotification,
    videoFinished,
    _playerItem);
timeJumpedNotification = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(
    AVPlayerItem.TimeJumpedNotification,
    videoFinished,
    _playerItem);
```

#### Test for the manual seek to end:

```
public void videoFinished(NSNotification notify){
    if (notify.Name == AVPlayerItem.TimeJumpedNotification) {
        Console.WriteLine ("{0} : {1}", _playerItem.Duration, _player.CurrentTime);
        if (Math.Abs(_playerItem.Duration.Seconds - _player.CurrentTime.Seconds) < 0.001) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Seek to end by user");
        }
    } else if (notify.Name == AVPlayerItem.DidPlayToEndTimeNotification) {
        Console.WriteLine ("Normal finish");
    } else {
        // PlaybackStalledNotification, ItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeErrorKey, etc...
        Console.WriteLine (notify.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I asked for, thank you. The only issue I now face is that I'd like to wait until the user has taken their finger off the seekbar before moving on, rather than immediately moving page whilst they may still be seeking...

Comment: You might want to ask another question concerning your followup question. The issue that I ran into is `AVPlayerViewController` subclassing to get access to the controls is out of the question as Apple actually states not to subclass that view and I found out things break very quickly. Two different projects: One I dropped `AVPlayerViewController` and wrote my own view for `AVPlayer`, in the other, I added an transparent overlay to the view to track touches and than recursively descend into the `AVPlayerViewController` subviews to determine what is on the screen under the user's touch, yuk :-/

Comment: Ooft, that sounds brutal. I'm quite new to all of this, so both approaches sound quite intimidating! It's not mission critical that the app waits for seeking to end, just a 'could have', so I may leave for now and focus on the Android port I've neglected til today. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: np, again, ask another question about that as I 'assume` someone smarter than me has come with a way to add touch delegates/events to the controls within `AVPlayerViewController`, even a crude dirty flag to track if the seek bar is in use would solve it for your use-case.

Comment: Followed up at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045949/detect-tap-on-off-avplayerviewcontroller-controls