# Detect tap on / off AVPlayerViewController controls

Tags: ios, xamarin, avplayer, xamarin.forms, avplayerviewcontroller

Based on the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35017037/detect-user-skipping-to-end-of-avplayer-video), I have implemented an event handler that detects when an `AVPlayerItem` finishes 'naturally'(through `AVPlayerItem.DidPlayToEndTimeNotification`) and when it finishes because the user has used the seek bar to reach the end of the video (through `AVPlayerItem.TimeJumpedNotification`).

I would like to extend this further by checking, in the event handler for the second case, whether the user has stopped seeking - i.e their finger has been lifted from the screen) or whether they're still actively seeking.

Is there any way to detect events on the `AVPlayerViewController` controls so I can perform this check and react accordingly?